# ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: name (option)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, execjs

My app runs fine on local environment. I was trying to `git push` a build to heroku. My commands are:

```
bundle install
git add .
git commit -am "abcdef"
git push heroku master
```

I then encountered an issue with assets:precompile

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2016-01-04T08:32:35.471098 #1018]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5d68c6d2f7845ca719a5f77705a12798/public/assets/recruiters-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js
remote:        I, [2016-01-04T08:32:35.471825 #1018]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5d68c6d2f7845ca719a5f77705a12798/public/assets/recruiters-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js.gz
remote:        I, [2016-01-04T08:32:35.477826 #1018]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5d68c6d2f7845ca719a5f77705a12798/public/assets/recruiters-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css
remote:        I, [2016-01-04T08:32:35.477974 #1018]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5d68c6d2f7845ca719a5f77705a12798/public/assets/recruiters-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css.gz
remote:        I, [2016-01-04T08:32:35.575303 #1018]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5d68c6d2f7845ca719a5f77705a12798/public/assets/events-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js
remote:        I, [2016-01-04T08:32:35.575465 #1018]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5d68c6d2f7845ca719a5f77705a12798/public/assets/events-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js.gz
remote:        I, [2016-01-04T08:32:35.623887 #1018]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5d68c6d2f7845ca719a5f77705a12798/public/assets/events-31e95c603f03e300e73e01cd6ee747799da57b4d12924aa979e0fa0749681cca.css
remote:        I, [2016-01-04T08:32:35.624406 #1018]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5d68c6d2f7845ca719a5f77705a12798/public/assets/events-31e95c603f03e300e73e01cd6ee747799da57b4d12924aa979e0fa0749681cca.css.gz
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: name (option) (line: 242, col: 14, pos: 7159)
remote:        Error
remote:        at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20160104-1018-1ens1gjjs:2659:11936)
remote:        at js_error (/tmp/execjs20160104-1018-1ens1gjjs:2659:12155)
remote:        at croak (/tmp/execjs20160104-1018-1ens1gjjs:2659:20622)
remote:        at token_error (/tmp/execjs20160104-1018-1ens1gjjs:2659:20759)
remote:        at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20160104-1018-1ens1gjjs:2659:20847)
remote:        at semicolon (/tmp/execjs20160104-1018-1ens1gjjs:2659:21320)
remote:        at simple_statement (/tmp/execjs20160104-1018-1ens1gjjs:2659:24179)
remote:        at /tmp/execjs20160104-1018-1ens1gjjs:2659:22152
remote:        at /tmp/execjs20160104-1018-1ens1gjjs:2659:21493
remote:        at block_ (/tmp/execjs20160104-1018-1ens1gjjs:2659:26198)new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):2659:11936)
remote:        js_error ((execjs):2659:12155)
remote:        croak ((execjs):2659:20622)
remote:        token_error ((execjs):2659:20759)
remote:        unexpected ((execjs):2659:20847)
remote:        semicolon ((execjs):2659:21320)
remote:        simple_statement ((execjs):2659:24179)
remote:        (execjs):2659:22152
remote:        (execjs):2659:21493
remote:        block_ ((execjs):2659:26198)
```

Note that I have controller-specific assets compile (see below). I wonder if that would cause the issue.

**views/layout/application.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", params[:controller], :media => "all", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', params[:controller], 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

**initializers/assets.rb**

```
# Compile controller assets
%w( recruiters events forms candidates ).each do |controller|
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["#{controller}.js", "#{controller}.css"]
end
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

**Update**
I was able to locate where the issue is from. Though I'm not sure what is wrong and why it works fine locally.

```
 238        if (fieldClass.match(/(select|checkbox-group|radio-group)/)) {
 239          previewData.values = [];
 240  
 241          $('.sortable-options li', field).each(function() {
 242            let option = {};
      ==============^
      SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
 243            option.selected = $('.select-option', $(this)).is(':checked');
 244            option.value = $('.option-value', $(this)).val();
 245            option.label = $('.option-label', $(this)).val();
 246  
 247            previewData.values.push(option);
 248          });
 249        }
```

[Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WtRU.png)

Comment: Had a similar error due to following code:
`debugger`
`var conversion = {};`

There was no semicolon after `debugger`, though there was a new line.

Answer (score 21):

By updating the js syntax, I was able to resolve the issue and the asset precompilation went successfully.

**original**

```
let option = {};
```

**updated**

```
var option = {};
```

Comment: Any idea why this happened since the original is valid JS ?

Comment: `let` is ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar while upgrading the codebase to Rails 7. You can add ES6 support via harmony which takes advantage of ES6 support in browsers and generally makes JS files smaller. You just need to add :

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

to your config/environments/production.rb

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the asset compilation was successful in production, but on staging it's giving the above error. So I checked the nodejs version on production and staging. On production it's v12.10.0 and on staging it's v10.XX.XX. So I updated the nodejs version to v12.10.0 on staging and it is working now.